# Search by select categories and subcategories for name

Tags: jquery, firebase, datatables

I have a page that shows in a table the name, category, and subcategory that it belongs to.

I'm trying to deploy category category search and sub catetegories through a select. It is working, I select a subcategory and the datatables searches the table for their correspondents, but when I go back and select a category the searches do not occur correctly, it searches with the table that was drawn in the previous search, that is, in the search of subcategories, and does not show all matches of rows that have the same string selected.

My select code is:

```
$("#select-categories").each( function ( i ) {
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="" id="Todos" class="optionGroup">Todas</option></select>')
                  .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
                  .on( 'change', function () {
                      if ($('#select-categories option:selected').prevUntil("option.optionGroup").prev().val() != undefined){

                        var catTerm = $('#select-categories option:selected').prevUntil("option.optionGroup").prev().val()
                        var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase(),
                        regexSub = '\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b';
                        regexCat = '\\b' + catTerm + '\\b';
                        table.column(2)
                            .search( regexCat, true, false ).column(3).search( regexSub, true, false)
                            .draw();
                        $('#tableCustom_filter > label > input[type="search"]').val('')
                      }
                      else if ($('#select-categories option:selected').prevUntil("option.optionGroup").prev().val() == undefined) {
                        if ($('#select-categories option:selected').attr("id") == 'categoria'){

                        var catTerm = $('#select-categories option:selected').prev().val()
                        var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase(),
                        regexSub = '\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b';
                        regexCat = '\\b' + catTerm + '\\b';
                        table.column(2)
                            .search( regexSub, true, false )
                            .draw();
                        $('#tableCustom_filter > label > input[type="search"]').val('')
                        }
                        else {
                          var catTerm = $('#select-categories option:selected').prev().val()
                          var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase(),
                          regexSub = '\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b';
                          regexCat = '\\b' + catTerm + '\\b';
                          table.column(2)
                              .search( regexCat, true, false ).column(3).search( regexSub, true, false)
                              .draw();
                          $('#tableCustom_filter > label > input[type="search"]').val('')
                        }
                      }
                      else if($('#select-categories option:selected').attr("id") != 'Todos'){

                        var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase(),
                        regex = '\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b';
                        table.column(2)
                            .search( regex, true, false )
                            .draw();
                        $('#tableCustom_filter > label > input[type="search"]').val('')
                      } 
                      else{
                        window.location = "/condominios";
                      }

                  });




        });
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum verifiable example needed to answer your question.

Comment: I edited the code